# Leaflet js access the content of a svg imageOverlay

Tags: svg, leaflet

I am trying to build a siteplan navigation using leafletjs and svg layers. I have 3 layers one on top of another (a base layer, a labels layer and a navigation layer which should react pretty much like a html image map) and I need to be able to click on elements in the svg of the top layer to display different data.

I would have used geoJson but all my data comes as Illustrator files which I can easily output as SVG files.

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Thank you,
Anton

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are encountering in doing this? Creating a [mcve] would likely help us understand your issue.

Comment: What @RobertLongson says, please give us an example of what you're trying to accomplish, highlight what the problems are. We'll help